How can I connect to a VPN using Node.js?
I am working on a project where both the frontend and backend are implemented using Node.js, and we are using .hbs (Handlebars) files for rendering data on the frontend.
I need to connect my system to a VPN (or OpenVPN) programmatically as part of this project. Is it possible to achieve this using Node.js? If so, could you provide guidance or examples on how to implement this?
I am using 9.11.0
just R & D. but haven't got satisfactory solutions.

If it helps and is sufficient for your usecase, I wrote a thing that leverages tunsocks to connect to a VPN and expose it as a SOCKS proxy, which is easy to use from wherever: https://github.com/akx/openconnect-socks-proxy

In order to connect to a VPN programatically in Node.js, you have to first choose any VPN service provider that has its own Node.js documentation, and read that service provider's documentation.
For instance, I generally use the

node-openvpn

module for connecting to my VPN server using the OpenVPN client itself.
const openvpn = require("node-openvpn"); // After installing the node-openvpn module writing npm install node-openvpn

const vpnClientOptions = {
    port: 1818,
    host: "185.255.95.248"
};
const serverAuthorization = {
    user: "private_username",
    pass: "private_password"
};

const openVPNClient = openvpn.connect(vpnClientOptions);

openVPNClient.on("connected", () => openvpn.authorize(serverAuthorization));

openVPNClient.on("error", (err) => {
    throw err;
});

OpenVPN Client Documentation Link: Documentation for the node-openvpn module
